# NodeJS: Returning an array to next promise asynchronously

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, phantomjs-node

I am familiar with asynchronous programming and using callbacks, however I am not as knowledgeable in using promises. I have the following code:

```
page.evaluate(function() {
        elements.push(document.getElementById('form_username'));
        elements.push(document.getElementById('form_password'));
        return elements;

    }).then(function(html){
        console.log(html[0].className);

    }).then( () => { 
        _page.close();
        _ph.exit();    

    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I am getting an error saying that 0 doesnt exist for type undefined when I pass it to 'html' and try to get the className, and I believe that is the case because when I return elements it doesnt wait the HTML elements to get pushed in because it is Asynchronous. I know that I can use callback(elements) if I were using callbacks, but I am not sure what to do in this case.

EDIT: page.evaluate() is a function used by phantomjs-node, found here https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node. Also this is just a piece of the code. When returning just a single HTML element I am able to get its className. Like this:

```
page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.getElementById('form_username');

    }).then(function(html){
        console.log(html.className);

    }).then( () => { 
        _page.close();
        _ph.exit();    

    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: What is `elements` declared as?  Is it a regular array?  Or something different?  `.push()` on a regular array is NOT asynchronous.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `document.getElementById('form_username')` is returning a valid DOM element.  To debug, you should check that before doing a `.push()` on it.

Comment: I'm not sure about my conclusion, but I just want to point out that `elements` is not returning a valid Promise so that the `.then` the function will be not executed as expected

Comment: @FelixFong - `return elements` is going back to the `page.evaluate()` callback (whatever that is).  For the `.then()` handler to work, `page.evaluate()` needs to return a promise.

Comment: What is `page.evaluate()`?  Can you point to some doc for that?

Comment: IIRC the `evaluate` function of phantomjs does not support closures.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am using page.evaluate from the node-phantom npm library. https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node This is only a piece of the code. elements is declared as an empty array.

Comment: @Bergi what do you mean that it does not support closures?

Comment: @HarounAnsari [The docs state](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) that "*The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.

Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will not work!*"

Comment: @Bergi so I should be able to return it all as an object instead of an array then. I will try it out.

Comment: No, an array should work as well. You just must create it within the evaluated function.

Comment: I defined the array/object within the evaluated function and it is still getting undefined when passed to the next .then()

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `elements` is in your `evaluate`. However, you really should just return something like this instead:

```
page.evaluate(function() {
  return [document.getElementById('form_username'), document.getElementById('form_password')];
})
```

And as others have suggested, I am not too sure if returning DOM objects works. It will serialize to JSON just fine but you can't call any DOM objects. I.e the above would not work with `elements[0].getAttrinute('name')`. Only data is passed, because phantomjs is a **different process**. So all data is serialized.

It would be best to pass what you need. Something like this:

```
return [document.getElementById('form_username').className, document.getElementById('form_password').className]
```

Disclaimer: I am amir20 on Github and the owner of this repo.

If you want to be happier in life, I highly recommend using `async/await` instead of `Promises`.

Comment: Thank you, should I post my further questions here, or on the issues of the github repo?

Comment: If you found a bug then put on Github. But for questions on over all Javascript I would do here.